# How to calculate species density from a given equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, physics

I am trying to calculate the species density for a mixture of gases using the following equation:

$$P = \sum_{k=1}^n \rho_k*\frac{1}{M_k}*T$$

where:

$P$ is the pressure of the mixture,
$T$ is the temperature of the mixture,
$n$ is the total number of species in the mixture,
$\rho_k$ is the density of species $k$,
$M_k$ is the molecular weight of species $k$.

I know the values of pressure, temperature, and molecular weights of each species. However, I'm not sure how to calculate the species density from this equation. Can someone please provide a step-by-step explanation of how to rearrange and solve this equation to find the species density for each gas species in the mixture?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How is $M$ in your equation related to the $M_k$ you know? What is $w$? Spend a bit more time with your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The question is edited

Comment: you have $1$ equation and $n$ unknowns, you will not be able to solve for the densities if $n>1$

Comment: @w Well. If I substitute _k_ =1 to _n_ in the equation, don't I have _n_ equation and _n_ unknowns?

Comment: $k$ is what you are using to index through the sum, it is not something you substitute. You have $P = ( \rho_1 * \frac{1}{M_1} * T_1 ) + ( \rho_2 * \frac{1}{M_2} * T_2 ) + \dots + ( \rho_n * \frac{1}{M_n} * T_n)$. As you can see, $k$ does not appear here. Furthermore, you have $n$ unknowns, namely $\rho_1, \rho_2 , \dots , \rho_n$, but only $1$ equation. Therefore, this equation only has an exact solution if $n = 1$.